# How to retrieve exact url in a asp.net web application which uses the UIP application block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, url, application-blocks

The incoming URL in this application has some URL parms but when I put a breakpoint on the base page, all I see is the internally UIP mapped URL which loses the parm information.

So, for UIP based applications what is the method to retrieve the original URL?

I tried `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` but it just gives the ../index.aspx url instead of the non-templated url which is incoming.

Comment: Have you checked Request.Headers["Host"]? You can combine that with the relative URL to get an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the property [Request.Url.OriginalString;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx)

The property gets the original URI string that was passed to the Uri constructor.